# What are the limitations of simulating grand unification theories of elementary particles in condensed matter settings?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, simulations, symmetry-breaking, grand-unification

What are the limitations of simulating grand unification theories of elementary particles in condensed matter settings?

I know that condensed matter systems can be constructed to be described by any of the popular Lie group candidates for GUT's via mean field theory, but where do the implications of analogy per analog end? After much searching in the literature, I have yet to encounter anything beyond vague existence postulates.

Comment: What is your definition of a "condensed matter system"? Also, please narrow down a bit what "limitations" you are looking for, right how this seems very broad.

Comment: @ACuriousMind Perhaps "low energy" is a better description than "condensed matter" in this context? "Low energy" here meaning (quasi-)precisely that the temperature is much lower than the characteristic energy scales of the many-body system, e.g. the chemical potential for a Fermi gas. This definition includes the majority of popular systems in both traditional and modern condensed matter physics, while explicitly excluding high-energy/cosmological scenarios which represent the phenomena one is trying to simulate in the first place.

Comment: Not sure about there being that much analogy, after all. The whole reason for GUTs is to describe physics on many orders of magnitude of energy/momentum scale, while in solid state physics the interesting stuff usually happens on one or two orders of magnitude. I am not aware of anybody trying to simulate the whole range of effects of cold matter all the way from the femto-Kelvin range (which would be boring) to the plasma phase with a single approach. I am not even sure that's a promising approach. It doesn't sound promising. Is that your question?

Comment: @CuriousOne If you don't mind, I am curious as to what your background is?

Comment: @beef42: I have done experimental solid state physics and experimental high energy physics. Solid state physicists are typically very focused on narrow temperature ranges, because that's where the important stuff happens. There are a few scaling law type things that matter (like conductivity or heat capacity as a function of temperature) but most researched phenomena are happening in a rather narrow (less than one order of magnitude) temperature range. In comparison, high energy physics asks for an explanation of every scale between neutrino masses and the Planck Scale at once.

Comment: There are analogies.  The idea started in condensed matter.  there are people working on it, for example   http://arxiv.org/pdf/cond-mat/9812381.pdf  http://arxiv.org/pdf/1211.2242.pdf  http://www.spacetimesociety.org/Bain.html  http://ltl.tkk.fi/ULTI_projects/EU_ULTI.php?function=search&id=93  http://indico.ph.ed.ac.uk/indico/getFile.py/access?resId=5&materialId=slides&confId=5  http://dao.mit.edu/~wen/pub/uni.pdf